# Saving ModelForm progress values to session in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have flow where users can create (model) forms. If form is valid, object gets saved and flow continues, but selection is in multiple pages. I need to keep current state of created object, which cannot be saved before it's completely valid.
One thing I can do is to always pass things around those views in the ModelForm to make sure, that user never loses data, but I also wanna make sure, that if he leaves the flow and comes back, he doesn't lose data, that he already entered previously.

That's why I decided I wanna save all the fields to session.

- Is this correct approach?
- How would you do this?
- Where would you put this session logic?
- What's best way of getting the fields from incomplete form to be saved?

Edit:

Please don't give me advice on how to use session, I am talking more about high level logic and architecture than specific implementation.

I should describe my flow a bit more. Model has 3 fields.

- normal dropdown (foreign key referencing another model)
- textfield
- another foreign key, but this time not done by select, but it's own separate page with lots of filters to help user pick the right (foreign) model

Flow is not linear, because user can start in different parts of page.

Sometimes user can go to page, where he has first 2 fields + button "Browse", which takes you to selection page for 3rd field. Then after he selects field there, he comes back.
But sometimes he selects first this field and then comes to screen with 2 remaining fields, where he needs to fill those.

Comment: Hard to say without specific examples of what you want to do, but `sessions` are a typical way of doing something like this. In each view you could check for certain session keys and execute some code based off that. `if 'sessionKey' in request.session: ...`

Comment: I described my flow a bit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

django-formtools offers a great way to do this using Form wizard.

> The form wizard application splits forms across multiple Web pages. It
> maintains state in one of the backends so that the full server-side
> processing can be delayed until the submission of the final form.

More info here https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know this library! However this doesn't work for my usecase, because my flow is not linear, user can start flow by filling different pieces of model and kind of jump around.

Answer (score 0):

to save in session:
`request.session["variable_name"] = "value"`
to get from session `request.session["variable_name"]`. sure you can use `request.session.get("..")` in both too

Comment: I know how to save and load from session. I just want clean solution, without too much spagetti :-)